# C# program mapping to excel runs too long issue

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# program that maps legacy text file report to an excel sheet. it works but it takes too long to run.
I wasn't sure how but i read that one problem is using the IF statement that I should change that to the SWITCH clause. How do i do that?
here is a typical case.

```
     else if (line.Contains("BILLING PARTY 1")) {
                        string billingParty1 = line.Replace("BILLING PARTY 1", "");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(billingParty1)){
                            patient.BillingParty1 = billingParty1.Trim();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with your Excel problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That advice doesn't look like it applies here.  You can use a `switch` statement to replace a long chain of `if`s where you are checking to see if a field matches some value.  For example:

```
if(foo == bar){
    Do1();
}
else if(foo == baz){
    Do2()
}
```

becomes

```
switch(foo)
{
    case bar:
       Do1();
       break;
    case baz:
       Do2();
       break;
}
```

In this case, it's likely the compiler could generate faster code.  But it seems like you have some more complicated conditions in your `if` statements as opposed to simple equality, so you won't be able to use a `switch`, because in a `switch`,

> Each case label specifies a constant value.

[MS Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)